# Overlay - insert into a sequence of itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

This is what I want to implement:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1st
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 2nd
            \item 3rd
        \end{itemize}
        \item 5th
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 6th
            \item 7th
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    An image to show in 4th
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The itemize shows its 1st 2nd and 3rd item, then An image shows in the 4th, then back to the rest of the itemize, still one by one. How can I implement this with overlay?

**EDIT** I know this can be done by manually adding <1->, <2->, ... for every item. I want to know if there is any method more automatic, just like using `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`to replace manually adding <+-> after each `\item`. Because I may want to change the sequence and changing these numbers one by one can be inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to *cheat* the `beamerpauses` counter when required.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+-> 1st
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> 2nd
            \item<+-> 3rd
        \end{itemize}
        % Shift the <+> counter by 1
        \addtocounter{beamerpauses}{1}
        \item<+-> 5th
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<+-> 6th
            \item<+-> 7th
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics<4->[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I meant that if there is any way other than hard coding, say if I have much more than 7 items, or I need to adjust the sequence and I want to prevent manually change these numbers again.

Comment: It could be working with `\pause` and `<+->` if all your content was sequential, but it is not the case here

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I added something possibly closer to what you want

Comment: @AlexanderZhang, did you have a look at my last edit ?

Comment: This seems to be a relatively pretty method, and it still works with `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` which can make it easier when editing.